# Beautifulsoup: Removing German Umlauts

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-unicode

i'm new to all of this, so i need a little bit of help. For a uni project i am trying to extract ingedrients from a website and in general the code works how it should, but i just don't know how
to get "Bärlauch" instead of "B%C3%A4rlauch" in the end.

I used beautifulsoup with the following code:

```
URL = [...]

links = []

for url in range(0,10):
    req = requests.get(URL[url])
    soup = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
    
    for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        links.append(str(link.get('href')))
```

I don't get why it doesn't work as it should, eventhough the encoding already is utf-8.
Maybe someone knows better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs are URL-encoded. The response of a request ist a `response` not a `req`(uest).

```
URLS = [...]

links = []
for url in URLS:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links.append(urllib.parse.unquote(link.get('href')))
```